# save image files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, save

How can we save image files (types such as jpg or png) in C#?

Comment: This question is very vague, can you provide more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: He wanted to know how to save an image, thats what he got.

Comment: hi, it's true, my means was what that you said.
but i'm she :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in c# us the Image.Save Method with these parameters (string Filename , ImageFormat)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx

Is that all you needed?

```
// Construct a bitmap from the button image resource.
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(typeof(Button), "Button.bmp");

// Save the image as a GIF.
bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Answer (score 19):

```
Image bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\\MyFile.bmp");
bitmap.Save("C:\\MyFile2.bmp");
```

You should be able to use the [Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx) from the [Image Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) and be just fine as shown above.  The Save Method has 5 different options or overloads...

```
  //Saves this Image  to the specified file or stream.
  img.Save(filePath);

  //Saves this image to the specified stream in the specified format.
  img.Save(Stream, ImageFormat);

  //Saves this Image to the specified file in the specified format.
  img.Save(String, ImageFormat);

  //Saves this image to the specified stream, with the specified encoder and image encoder parameters.
  img.Save(Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);

  //Saves this Image to the specified file, with the specified encoder and image-encoder parameters.
  img.Save(String, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more extensive image handling than the .Net Framework provides out of the box, check out the [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) project

Answer (score 0):

```
SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog();
sv.Filter = "Images|*.jpg ; *.png ; *.bmp";
ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;

if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    switch (sv.Filter )
    {
        case ".jpg":
            format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            break;
        case ".png":
            format = ImageFormat.Png;
            break;
        case ".bmp":
            format = ImageFormat.Bmp;
            break;
    }
    pictureBox.Image.Save(sv.FileName, format);
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue