# C# Save picturebox as jpeg with Save dialogue box

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a jpeg shown in a picturebox on my WinForm program, I want to save this to a jpeg file and have the standard 'Save' dialogue box so I can select a location, how can I do this in C#?

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this post: [save image files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290644/save-image-files-in-c)

And then look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx