# InitialDirectory not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

VERY VERY new to C Sharp, as it's not part of my study path, but I have to edit small codes in C Sharp in order for my app to work. I'm using Ogama, a open source gaze tracker, which I need for my project. The heatmap, to be more specific. Now, I want to save the heatmap to a directed folder, and managed to find the code. The initial code was

```
 public static bool ExportImageToFile(Image image)
{
  SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
  dlg.Title = "Please enter filename for image...";
  dlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.ToString();
```

So I thought I could change it, by following other tutorials online, and this was my code.

```
public static bool ExportImageToFile(Image image)
{
  SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
  dlg.Title = "Please enter filename for image...";
dlg.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "heatmapimages");
```

But it doesn't work. When I click the save file button, it brings me to where my Ogama projects are. The 'heatmapimages' folder is in my Desktop. Any advice? Thank you in advance.
EDIT: Managed to make it work, by changing Special.Personal to Special.DesktopDirectory. Is there a way to make it autosave the image? Such that I don't need to click save?

Comment: It looks like you want [`SpecialFolder.Desktop`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/634145/21475) instead of `Personal`?

Comment: @Cameron, yeap! Decided to try and change to Desktop.Directory, and it worked! Is there anyway that it will auto save the image? And such that I don't need to click save?

Comment: Your autosave question would be better served if you asked a new question; we try to keep each question focused on just a single topic at a time.

Comment: @Exclusified: See here on how to save an image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290644/save-image-files-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, noted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [RestoreDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) `true` and set InitialDirectory to `SpecialFolder.Desktop`. Here are all [SpecialFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) for your reference.

It restores the current directory to its original value if the user changed the directory while searching for files.